# Magento How to convert the order amount from AED to USD while transferring order info to express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, magento-1.7

I want to transfer the order amount from AED currency to USD currency. My Base currency is United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED), but Paypal Express-checkout does not support the AED currency. How can I convert AED order amount to USD while transferring the information to Paypal Express-checkout?

Is it possible to transfer the order to paypal with USD even though the Base Currency is AED?

Is it possible to convert order into USD before sending it to paypal even though my base currency is AED?

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar issue, but solution was not that elegant: before sending amount in currency XXX I had to convert it in USD like `$usd_price = round($local_currency_price * $exchange_rate, 2)`, where `$exchange_rate` is either edited manually through admin panel or whatever, or (if you are real deal) got via cURL from services that provide such information.